# How to sort List of string with delimiters by ascending and descending order

Tags: java, list, sorting, data-structures, comparator

I need to sort a List of String  based on different delimiters in the key. Key is concatenation of date,title,source,author. I need to sort the list by date in descending order and then by title and source in ascending order. All the values may or may not be null except for author.
I add '#' as delimiter for to separate date from title,source and author
I add '|' in place of title and source if they are null.
I add '*' in place of date if date is null

```
Systen.out.print(listToSortKeys):
[2015-03-26 00:00:00.0#CAB,2015-03-26 00:00:00.0#ABC, 2011-06-29 00:00:00.0#EFG, 2011-06-29 00:00:00.0#DFG, *#||D, *#||C, *#|C2, *#|C1]
```

How can I achieve this using comaparator:

```
Comparator<String> cmp = new Comparator<String>() {
          public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
              String[] keySplit1 = o1.split("#",2);
              String[] keySplit2 = o2.split("#",2);
              try{
              if(!keySplit1[0].equals("*") && !keySplit2[0].equals("*")){ // if date is not null compare and sort in descending order
                      int dateCompare = sfd.parse(keySplit1[0]).compareTo(sfd.parse(keySplit2[0]));
                        if(dateCompare == -1){
                            return 1;
                        }
                      return dateCompare;

                }
              if(keySplit1[0].equals("*") && keySplit2[0].equals("*")){ // if both the date are null then do normal sort on string
                  return o1.compareTo(o2);
              }
              if((keySplit1[0].equals("*") && !keySplit2[0].equals("*")) || (!keySplit1[0].equals("*") && keySplit2[0].equals("*"))){  // if one of date is null then move it towards end of list
                  if(keySplit1[0].equals("*")){
                      return -1;  // line 18
                  }else{
                      return 1;   // line 20
                  }
              }
              }catch(Exception e){      
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              return keySplit1[1].compareTo(keySplit2[1]);

          }
          };
          Collections.sort(listToSortTheKeys, cmp);
```

Output1:

```
[*#|C1,*#|C2,*#||C,*#||D,2015-03-26 00:00:00.0#CAB, 2015-03-26 00:00:00.0#ABC, 2011-06-29 00:00:00.0#EFG, 2011-06-29 00:00:00.0#DFG]
```

if I interchange the returning values in line 18 and line 20 then I get

Output2:

```
[2015-03-26 00:00:00.0#CAB, 2015-03-26 00:00:00.0#ABC, 2011-06-29 00:00:00.0#EFG, 2011-06-29 00:00:00.0#DFG, *#|C1, *#|C2, *#||C, *#||D]
```

Expected Output:

```
[2015-03-26 00:00:00.0#ABC,2015-03-26 00:00:00.0#CAB,2011-06-29 00:00:00.0#DFG,2011-06-29 00:00:00.0#EFG,*#|C1,*#|C2,*#||C,*#||D]
```

Comment: how about instead of doing any of the comparisons yourself, convert each record into a string which would then naturally sort by the rules you describe. e.g. make a normalise method, which does the conversion and then the comparator would be public int compare(String o1, String o2) { return normalise(o1).compareTo(normalise(o2)) }

Comment: oh you mentioned a mix of ascending and descending.. my idea might not work so well for that

Comment: The problem arise when I need to sort it in descending order by date but ascending order by remaining string. What I am not sure of is can we perform descending order and ascending order sort using single comparator.

Comment: `if(dateCompare == -1){ return 1; } return dateCompare;` is obviously wrong, for multiple reasons. First, the sign matters, a `compare` method is not required to return exactly `-1`. Second, converting negative numbers to positive but letting positive number remain positive, can’t establish a correct comparison result. Third, the subsequent unconditional return ignores the fact, that the result could be `0`, implying equal, in which case the secondary criteria should get evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When both the dates are not null and you compare them, then you should handle case when both the dates are same, then you should sort by the title and author in ascending order.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. I tried with couple other examples and it works perfectly smaller set however, when trying with larger set say 1000 strings for some reason it does not. However I got it working by splitting it into two list one with date field and one with null, then sorting and merge. I will accept your answer as well. Thanks.